# What generates .pz~ backup files from .py files?

Tags: save

I've been doing edit-save-run-bugfix-repeat on a Python test script, using `vim` as my editor. My directory now looks like this:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 james james   458 Nov 29 23:02 test.pr~*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 james james   504 Nov 29 22:53 test.ps~*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 james james   485 Nov 29 22:51 test.pt~*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 james james   503 Nov 29 22:48 test.pu~*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 james james   504 Nov 29 22:48 test.pv~*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 james james   485 Nov 29 22:40 test.pw~*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 james james   262 Nov 29 22:36 test.px~*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 james james   456 Nov 29 23:04 test.py*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 james james    96 Nov 28 22:29 test.py~*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 james james   109 Nov 29 22:20 test.pz~*
```

I was only expecting to see `test.py`. I'm guessing it was `vim` that did this, as they appear to be backups of the file taken at various stages of editing. But why?

Edit: here is my `.vimrc` file:

```
" My Vim config file
" The directory setting is a comma separated list of directories where
" vim should place swapfiles. Each path is tried in order and the first
" one that doesn’t fail (because it doesn’t exist or for permissions
" reasons) is where vim will create swapfiles. By default on unix
" systems, it it set to “.,~/tmp,/var/tmp,/tmp” which means it first
" tries “.” or the same directory as the file being edited. By using ^=,
" we tell vim to prepend the given value to those already set (the
" defaults). This allows vim to fall back to other directories should
" the specified one fail for some reason (directory doesn’t exist or
" disk is full for example). The double slash at the end tells vim to
" form swap file names using the full path of the edited file, replacing
" / with %, avoiding name conflicts. See :help directory for more
" details.
set directory^=$HOME/.vim_swap//
set background=dark

set tw=120
au BufRead *.sh,*.py set tw=0
au BufRead *.txt set tw=80
syntax on
filetype on
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
inoremap <F5> <C-R>=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")<CR>
set hlsearch
set incsearch
set expandtab
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
"highlight OverLength ctermbg=red ctermfg=white guibg=#592929
"match OverLength /\%81v.*/

"Tell vim to remember certain things when we exit
"  '10  :  marks will be remembered for up to 10 previously edited files
"  "100 :  will save up to 100 lines for each register
"  :20  :  up to 20 lines of command-line history will be remembered
"  %    :  saves and restores the buffer list
"  n... :  where to save the viminfo files
set viminfo='10,\"100,:20,%,n~/.viminfo
function! ResCur()
  if line("'\"") <= line("$")
    normal! g`"
    return 1
  endif
endfunction

augroup resCur
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWinEnter * call ResCur()
augroup END

set cm=blowfish " default is zip; insecure.
```

Comment: That seems so strange. Will you show `~/.vimrc` and the system-wide vim RC file, wherever it is on your system?

Comment: Beats me. It "looks like" a bizarre combination of incremental backups (http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Keep_incremental_backups_of_edited_files) and swap file names (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326707/vim-what-are-all-the-possible-swapfile-extensions), but the RC files don't seem to configure anything like that. Maybe there are more vim RC files getting processed. I can't wait to learn the answer to this question.

Comment: This question is perfectly on topic and welcome to stay here. If *you* want to, I can migrate it to [vim.se] where there is a higher concentration of vim experts. If you'd like that, leave me a comment.

Comment: @terdon. Yes please.

Comment: Some output that might be useful: `:scriptnames` and `:au BufWritePost` and `:au CursorHold`